# How to add unclickable content into angular bootstrap accordion header?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The default  content in the accordion-heading will be all clickable to toggle the section, but now I need to add something else into header which is not clickable. How can do that?

```
<accordion-group is-open="OpenOneAtTime" ng-repeat="destination in mileage.destionations" style='position:relative;'>
    <accordion-heading>
        <!-- All I want is only make "Toggle Me" clickable, and leave other content in the header alone,just like pure text. -->
        <span ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': OpenOneAtTime, 'fa-chevron-right': !OpenOneAtTime}">Toggle Me</span>
        <span ng-show='!OpenOneAtTime'>{{destination.Total}}+{{destination.To}}</span>
    </accordion-heading>
    <div class='accordion-section'>
        main content
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not easy todo. I haven't seen any options from `angular-ui-bootstrap` side to change this.

But with CSS you could disable the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) from the anchor-tag with class `accordion-toggle` and re-enable the events for your `Toggle Me` text. It's a bit tricky.

Another thing you could try is to modify the `templateCache` for `template/accordion/accordion-group.html` and style it as you need it. That's probably better but I haven't tried this yet.

It should be possible to change that template during runtime to make a custom override. If not you could modify the source file of the template and adapt it but I would first try if you could override it somehow.

There are some points with the css approach not perfect and I'm not sure how to fix them:

1. Toggle me click will underline the whole heading
2. Active style and hovering from the link will keep the underline of the not clickable text active.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/as83t36b/).

**Update**:

In the master repo of `angular-ui-bootstrap` there you could pass `template-url` into `accordion-group` to use your custom template. It's a pretty new commit. [See here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/f777c320ccd45531490b2bbb58fd31e9c6472fdc).
The latest version `0.13.2` is with-out that feature but you can modify the template anyway but not so convenient.

I would now use the template approach because it's cleaner. If you have to modify the `Toggle Me!` text inside of the template with a scope variable you probably need to check if you can decorate the accordion-group directive to add that behaviour.

I've created another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jpLLvukz/) with the custom accordion template.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
    var itemCount = 0; // just to have an increasing title
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;
    $scope.mileage = {};
    $scope.mileage.destionations = [{
        Type: '',
        Reimbursable: "Yes",
        Distance: true,
        Odometer: false,
        total: itemCount,
        From: '',
        To: '',
        openState: true
    }];
    $scope.addNewDestination = function () {
        var index = $scope.mileage.destionations.length,
            openState = (index == 1);
        
        angular.forEach($scope.mileage.destionations, function(destination, index) {
            // turn all of except second
            destination.openState = (index == 1);
        });
        
        itemCount++;
        
        var newDestination = {
            type: '',
            reimbursable: "Yes",
            Distance: true,
            Odometer: false,
            total: itemCount,
            From: '',
            To: '',
            openState: openState
        };
        
        
        $scope.mileage.destionations.push(newDestination);
    }
    $scope.status = {
        isFirstOpen: true,
        isFirstDisabled: false
    };
}
```

```css
.accordion-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    /*cursor: default;
    */
    pointer-events: none;
}
.accordionSubtitle {
    display: inline-block;
    /*cursor: default;
    */
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.accordionSubtitle:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="destination.openState" ng-repeat="destination in mileage.destionations" is-disabled="false">
        <accordion-heading>
            <span class="accordionSubtitle">toggle me </span> - {{destination.total}} this text is not clickable<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
      {{destination|json}}
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
    <button ng-click="addNewDestination()">add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix if one understands event propagation and how to employ it. You need two directives. Let's call them clickable and unClickable.

```
.directive('clickable', function ()  {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function ()  {
                 //Do something here
            });
        }
    };
});

.directive('unClickable', function ()  {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e)  {
                  e.stopPropogation();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Events start on the element on which they are performed or triggered and then progress upwards through the DOM. The first directive will perform whatever task it is assigned in its click function. The second directive will cause an element to swallow any click that occurs on it or its children, unless the child has a click event that is called before the event is passes to the parent.

Comment: That's a good idea. Just the styling is a bit problematic. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/wvuL8cey/). I couldn't remove the underline on hover of the `not-clickable` directive. So I think the best is to work with the custom template.

Comment: I can't look at the fiddle on my phone but you could either remove the class on hover or intercept the hover inside of the unclickable directive.

Answer (score 0):

To improve **@AWolf**'s answer: you can also use **$event.stopPropagation()** in a ng-click located in the **accordion-heading** tag.

This allows you to assign another event on the text in case you need it (that was my case - to add an "edit" icon instead of a simple text).

See updated example here:

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
    var itemCount = 0; // just to have an increasing title
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;
    $scope.mileage = {};
    $scope.mileage.destionations = [{
        Type: '',
        Reimbursable: "Yes",
        Distance: true,
        Odometer: false,
        total: itemCount,
        From: '',
        To: '',
        openState: true
    }];
    $scope.addNewDestination = function () {
        var index = $scope.mileage.destionations.length,
            openState = (index == 1);
        
        angular.forEach($scope.mileage.destionations, function(destination, index) {
            // turn all of except second
            destination.openState = (index == 1);
        });
        
        itemCount++;
        
        var newDestination = {
            type: '',
            reimbursable: "Yes",
            Distance: true,
            Odometer: false,
            total: itemCount,
            From: '',
            To: '',
            openState: openState
        };
        
        
        $scope.mileage.destionations.push(newDestination);
    }
    $scope.status = {
        isFirstOpen: true,
        isFirstDisabled: false
    };
}
```

```css
.not_clickable:hover{
  cursor: default;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="destination.openState" ng-repeat="destination in mileage.destionations" is-disabled="false">
        <accordion-heading>
            <span class="accordionSubtitle">toggle me</span>
            <span ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" class="not_clickable"> - {{destination.total}} this text is not clickable<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
           </span>
        </accordion-heading>
      {{destination|json}}
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
    <button ng-click="addNewDestination()">add</button>
</div>
```